# Basic TCP client on Linux, OSX and Windows

Tags: c, linux, windows, macos, tcp

I want to make a TCP client that works on Windows, Linux and osx (most important) in C. The code that I've found on SO might work on linux but not on osx and vice versa. So what do I need to make sure that it works on all three?

Thanks!

Comment: Easiest route?  Search for and use an already established and debugged cross-platform library.

Comment: you might use the libraries provided by ACE or BOOST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are planning to write your code to use the BSD sockets API, you'll find that most TCP client code that works on Linux will work on MacOS/X with little or no modification, and vice versa.

Getting the code to work under Windows as well is a little bit trickier, as required #includes are different, and there are a number of cases where Windows' TCP stack (aka WinSock) behaves a little bit differently than that the TCP stacks of the other two OS's.  That said, Windows does support most of the BSD sockets API, and with a bit of #ifdef-ing you can come up with a program that will compile and run correctly on all three OS's.  You'll need to test and debug on all three OS's, of course; never assume that just because something works on one OS that it will work everywhere.

Depending on your program's particular needs (and your interests), it may well make sense to follow Duck's advice and find a networking library that has already done the above-described work for you; but if you prefer to "roll your own", that is doable too.  A good approach when writing to the BSD sockets API is:  whenever you find a piece of code that you have to write differently for different OS's, hide the implementations of that code snippet inside a function together (with an #ifdef so that the right code gets compiled under each OS), so that the rest of your program doesn't have to remember how to deal with that unpleasant detail anymore.  Do that enough times and you'll end up the proud maintainer of your own cross-platform networking library ;)

I'd recommend getting your program working under Linux and/or OS/X first, and once you're happy with it, then porting it over to Windows.  Some "gotchas" to watch out for when porting your network code to Windows:

1. Under Windows, you #include windows.h or winsock2.h to get the network definitions you need.  (If you want the newer WinSock2 API, you have to include winsock2.h, and always do it before any #include of windows.h, or you'll get the wrong API version... it's a real circus)
2. Under Windows you have to call WSAStartup() before doing any networking stuff (if you forget, all your networking calls will error out)
3. Under MacOS/X and Linux, file descriptors and sockets are largely interchangeable (i.e. you can select() on STDIN_FILENO, etc).  Under Windows, they are not.
4. Under MacOS/X and Linux, you can find out why a call failed by checking errno.  Under Windows, you call WSAGetLastError() instead.
5. Under MacOS/X and Linux, you destroy a socket with close().  Under Windows you do it with closesocket().
6. Under MacOS/X and Linux, you can (if you choose) call read() and write() on your TCP socket to receive/send data (respectively).  Under Windows, that won't work, you *must* call send() and recv() only.   (send() and recv() will work under MacOS/X and Linux too)
7. To set a socket to non-blocking mode under Windows, you have to call ioctlsocket(fd, FIONBIO, &mode).  Under MacOS/X and Linux, you call instead fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags).
8. More fun Windows-networking gotchas can be read at the [WinSock Lame List](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/lame-list.html).